# Nginx loosing header sometime

Tags: nginx

I am using nginx as reverse proxy server for android application(get/post requests only). Some of the data contained in the headers. In some cases nginx loses "id" or "fail_id" header.

config:

```
user user;

worker_processes 4;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

events {
    worker_connections 100000;
    use epoll;
}

http {
  upstream myproject {
    server 192.168.88.246:2053;
}

  server {
    listen 2054;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /home/user/android/cert/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/user/android/cert/key.pem;

    proxy_read_timeout 600;
    proxy_send_timeout 600;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://myproject;
      proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    }
  }
}
```

Could i set original headers of request?

Updated:
A more detailed study found that nginx miss "fail_id" header. All other headers are working.

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#underscores_in_headers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem solved!
Nginx default config misses headers with underscore.

This directive solved the problem:

```
underscores_in_headers on;
```

Comment: This directive needs to be added to http directive. You cannot add it to server directive. If you are creating an additional configuration file, add it above any upstream/server directives.

Answer (score -1):

Thank You For the underscore directive. I have used **underscores_in_headers on;** directive and the header value with underscore passed to my node app.

Now I am able to access header value (api_key) using postman request and angular request from the web.

But now when The request is raise from the android app and I have set the api_key in the android request header, I am unable to access the api_key.

My config is:

```js
server {
        listen 80;
  
        server_name uat.api.myserver.com;
        underscores_in_headers on;
  
       location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:9102;
       }
}
```

Comment: Stuck on the same issue.

Comment: The underscores directive can be added only to http section not to a server section. It should be above the server section in the example above